# TypeError: Cannot set property 'adress' of undefined at SafeSubscriber._next

Tags: node.js, angular

I m trying to pass the data to array which declared inside of component.But Im getting only first indexes of array.The other elements does not return.

I read that program works async and only get first index also they suggest to change var i in for loop to let i which ı changed it.

Component :

```
 weathers: Weather[] = [{adress:'',city:''}];
 weather: Weather;
 constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {
 }
 ngOnInit() {
 this.weatherService.getWeather().subscribe(weathers =>
{
  let size = (Object).keys(weathers).length;
  this.weathers =  Weather[size] = [{adress:'',city:''}];
  console.log(weathers);
  console.log(size);
    for(let i=0;i<size;i++) {
     const adress = weathers[i].adress;
     const city = weathers[i].city;
     this.weathers[i].adress=adress;
     this.weathers[i].city=city;
   }


  }
);
}
```

Service:

```
export class WeatherService {
weatherList: Weather[];
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
getWeather() {
return this.http.get<Weather>('/api/weathers');
}
}
```

Class:

```
  export class Weather {
  city: string;
  adress: string;
   }
```

ERROR TypeError:

```
Cannot set property 'adress' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber._next (weather.component.ts:31)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:124)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use arrays this way: `this.weathers =  Weather[size] = [{adress:'',city:''}];`. There is no need to set the size of an array when making it:

```
let size = (Object).keys(weathers).length;
this.weathers = [];
for(let i=0;i<size;i++) {
  const adress = weathers[i].adress;
  const city = weathers[i].city;
  this.weathers.push({'adress': adress, 'city': city});
}
```

An even better way to do this is using `map` operator

```
console.log(weathers);
this.weathers = (Object).keys(weathers).map(key => {
  return {
    adress: weathers[key].adress,
    city: weathers[key].city
  }
}
```